# Installing RHEL into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux, license

I have to practice, so I want to install RHEL onto my personal machine, but first I want to try installation onto VirtualBox on the same machine (you never know what may happen).

So the question is: **May I use the same registration info for both VirtualBox and the real machine?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RHEL Developer Subscription FAQ](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/no-cost-rhel-faq/):

> **8. How many Red Hat Enterprise Linux entitlements are included?**
>
> You may use this no-cost Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscription on one (1)
>   physical system with up to eight processor sockets. If you are using a system
>   with virtualization, you can installed an unlimited number of guest virtual
>   machines (VMs) on that system.

So I first tried it into VirtualBox and then installed on physical system. Now I have both Virtual machine and phisical system from one distro on the one machine under one developer subscription **and it's legal**.